# RecyclerView Items sometimes not expanding correctly. Best way to expand items?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Currently I have been trouble with making my RecyclerView items expandable. There should be only one Item expanded at a time. I have been achieving it with the following Code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final myViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    viewHolder.lytHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (currentItem != viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()) {
                currentItem = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                viewHolder.expand();
            }
        }
    });

    if (routineHolder.getAdapterPosition() == pointer) {
        viewHolder.expand();
    } else {
        viewHolder.collapse();
    }
}
```

`currentItem` is an Integer which points to the position of the currently expanded Item.

And in my ViewHolder I have these methods:

```
public void expand() {
    if (lytContent.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        lytContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (lytContent.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        lytContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void collapse() {
    lytContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

lytContent is the expandable Layout which is beneath the lytHeader which onClickListener makes the lytContent expanding.

First I thought this works well but after a while of testing I notices that sometimes lytContent won´t expand even though `lytContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` is being called. And furthermore, when I put in more then around 7 items, the items will never expand while `lytContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` still gets called.

I have no idea why this codes does not work and it has been driving me crazy for the last days. I thought about using some library for this, this way I could also use some expanding animations. I would really appreciate some tips and thoughts.

Comment: Where is `holder`? You have used it like `holder.expand();`. But I do not see any declaration.

Comment: I do not see any use of the `currentItem` as well in your `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: Sorry, with holder I meaned viewHolder. I changed some names for making this post clear. Now it is correct. Also currentItem is an integer variable in my RecyclerView adapter

Comment: Where do you set the `pointer` value which is used here - `routineHolder.getAdapterPosition() == pointer`? And what is `routineHolder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change onBindView as follow.

```html
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final myViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    if(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()==currentItem){
        viewHolder.expand();
    } else {
        viewHolder.collapse();
    }
 
    viewHolder.lytHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (currentItem != viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()) {
                currentItem = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();            
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

and change expand method as follow.

```html
public void expand() {
    lytContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void collapse() {
    lytContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. This code seems to work much better. Do you have an idea why my code didn´t work properly?

Comment: Inside your on click method else block you should have collapsed the item. Also after notifying data change you must have compared it with current item whereas you were comparing it with some pointer, which was not covered in the code you posted.

Comment: Hmm I called expand() in the else block to be able to expand and collapse the currentItem (So every item can be collapsed). Also the pointer is not in the "real" code, that was just a mistake when creating this post. My code did work almost like yours but I have some weird behavior with my RecyclerView where 'lytContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)' is called but the layout is not expanding. I just noticed that that happen with your code as well sometimes but I can´t figure out a pattern when his bug occurs.